# Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++, string, sqlite

I have been getting this error when I try to pass in SQL commands with quotation marks. Other simple queries are fine, just the ones with quotation marks or percentage symbol that gives me this error.

I tried passing it as an `output string stream` but I still got the same error.

```cpp
std::vector<Post *> sql::selectSpecificPosts(sqlite3 *db, int languageNum){
    sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    std::vector<Post *> posts;
    char *errMsg;
    std::string select;

    if (languageNum == 1) {
        select = "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE CONTENTTYPE = \'Kotlin\'";
    }else if (languageNum == 2){
        select = "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE CONTENTTYPE = \'Objective-C\'";
    }else if (languageNum == 3){
        select = "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE CONTENTTYPE = \'JavaScript\'";
    }

    sqlite3_exec(db, select.c_str(), post_callback, &posts, &errMsg);

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return posts;
}
```

Is there a better way to pass SQL query with quotation mark?

Comment: Use a prepared statement with a parameter bound to the appropriate value: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html (you shouldn't be using `sqlite3_exec()` for anything that returns data anyways. That callback function is way too cumbersome and arcane and inflexible to be usable)

Comment: You should also be checking all your function calls for errors...

Comment: It works with prepared statement. Thank you.